# PHP setup with Apache 2.2 on Windows 8, it only shows plaintext

Tags: php, html, apache, windows-8, windows-8.1

I am trying to get my info.php file to work, it has the code:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

When I hit localhost on my apache web server, i get the default "It works!" When I hit localhost/info.php I get the error message, oops chrome could not connect to localhost.

I do not understand why, I already added these two lines to my httpd.conf file in my apache conf folder:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Are there any other obscure things that I need to setup in order to get php to work? I am really baffled.

Comment: Have you considered to install WAMP to avoid manual configuration?

Comment: Yes but I would like to get it working from scratch this time.

Comment: @smuggledPancakes have you considered to use WPN-XM server stack instead. it comes with all kinds of goodies installed. imagemagick, pear, redis, memcache, et al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that it isn't

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Note the _ instead of . in the dll filename.

Comment: I corrected that spelling error in my code and my post. It still does not fix the issue though...